# How do i create a draggable and resizable element that snaps to a grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar, drag-and-drop

i'm currently working on a timetable function on a project. I want to make the event blocks draggable and resizable, but only on a 10px increment and be able to move them over to the other days/columns.

I want it to be exactly like how Google Calendar does it.
[How Google Calendar does it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd2cm.gif)

I've tried googling for some time now and ended up following the documentation on the drag and drop web API over at developer.mozilla.org, but find it quite daunting.

If you have successfully made something similar, how did you do it and what resources are available for this problem?

Comment: There are multiple open source libraries that will speed up your development. Is your app framework dependent? If so I would start with googling: "vue/react/angular drag and drop snap library". Most notable from Vue world are: Sortable JS, Draggable, Dragula. React community has many battle-tested libraries (can't give you any names of top of my head). If you are coding from scratch, open source it.

Comment: @Domatorov I'm using the TALL stack so i want to implement it just by using Alpine.js and vanilla javascript. I know there's libraries out there like Fullcalendar that does almost the same thing i need, but i need more customisation and also Fullcalendar Timetable is a premium feature that costs almost $500.